# Как проектировать классы с наследованием в Java?

Tags: java, ооп, наследование

Я изучаю Java, но вопрос скорее общий.

Наследник перенимает все методы и поля (все аспекты поведения и состояния) родителя, в том числе приватные. Но получается, что приватные поля и методы мы напрямую использовать в наследнике не можем, что не позволяет проектировать сущность наследника, опираясь на внутреннею реализацию родителя.

Например, создаем класс-родитель "Смартфон без NFC" и класс потомок "Смартфон с NFC". Допустим в классе "Смартфон без NFC" есть поле "вес". Целесообразно сделать его приватным, и добавить геттер.
Это нормально, что в таком случае в классе-потомке я смогу использовать это поле только посредством геттера? Получается, что объект-наследник не имеет прямого доступа к одному из основных своих свойств. Или все же здесь ошибка проектирования?

Или например я бы хотел определить метод "использовать NFC" в классе потомке. И для этого хотел бы использовать приватный метод "запуск системы" класса-родителя. Но делать этого я, очевидно, не могу. Писать его заново в потомке - неправильно, но и неправильно сделать его не-приватным в классе-родителе. Так как правильно поступить?

Comment: С точки зрения логики, смартфон с NFC никак не может быть потомком смартфона без NFC, потому что между ними нет отношения "является". Их можно наследовать от более абстрактного класса, например от класса "Смартфон", куда можно было бы вынести общие свойства и пометить их как protected. Помимо этого еще скажу, что не всегда нужно именно наследование. Вам стоит рассмотреть такую концепцию, как композиция. Если говорить простыми словами, то это когда ты кладешь к себе в класс объект нужно тебе класса и дергаешь его методы, вместо того, чтобы от него наследоваться

Answer (score 1):

Правильнее будет использовать **интерфейс**. Интерфейс - набор обещаний или можно назвать структурой класса.

Например:
Интерфейс смартфона

```
public interface Smartphone {
    public int weight();
}
```

И интерфейс модуля NFC, так как в смартфоне не всегда есть NFC, то лучше не обещать в интерфейсе смартфона данный метод.

```
public interface NfcModule {
    public boolean use();
}
```

И реализацию этого интерфейса с помощью `implements` создать классы.

```
public class SmartfoneMotorolla implements Smartphone, NfcModule {
    @Override
    public int weight() {
        //200 грам вес смартфона
        return 200;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean use() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Более подробно правила **ООП** с использованием интерфейса можно найти в концепции `SOLID`

Answer (score -1):

1. Объявите поле как protected.
2. Метод "Запуск системы" объявите как protected.